# Click Button Inside Telerik RadWindow Upon Opening

Tags: telerik, radwindow

Upon the click of a button, the RadWindow in question opens. Immediately after it finishes doing so, I'd like to click one of the buttons within it. Additionally, I'd like for the window to be hidden upon launch. Is there a simple way to do either of these? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Javascript the RadWindow is populated from, I used this.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
$telerik.$("#Submit1").click();
});
```